# Css width property is aligning content to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

What's upp guys, so every time I try to make a border of my inner divs fit the content of that div, so the borders length does not go across the page, the div ends up going to the left of my page. I am using the Css "width-fit content" property to achieve this, it does end up filling the empty space, but it shifts my content to the left of the page. I will put my CSS and JSX down below, I am building a Todo APP in react.

Small snippet of my CSS

```
 * {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #2d2d33;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 align-items: center;
 align-content: center;
 border-radius: 15px;
 box-sizing: border-box;

}
.reload {
  justify-content:left

}

header h1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: rgb(37, 54, 54);

}
.task {

  border: 3px solid rgb(99, 94, 94);
  width: fit-content
    
}

p {
  cursor: pointer; 
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  color: rgb(107, 101, 101);
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: ease-out 0.7s;
}
```

My JSX

```
 return (
    <div>
      <header>
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>
      <div className='input-task'>
        <input onChange={getTask}></input>
        <button onClick={displayTask}>AddTask</button>
      </div>
      <div className='display-task'>
        {task.map((item) => {
            return (
            <div className='task'>
              <h3>{item}</h3>
              <button className='delete-btn' onClick={() => deleteTask(item)}>Delete Task</button>
              <button className='complete-btn' onClick={() => deleteTask(item)}>Completed</button>

            </div>
            )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use flex for task class and justify center if you send a photo from your to do it will be better to us for help you

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, but that did not work either, I took a picture, but I do not know how to upload it here, maybe I will try editing the question.